# Grab the values from url that is in between specific characters BigQuery

Tags: parsing, url, google-bigquery, urlparse

I need to parse urls in order to grab a value that comes after `.com/` AND before the next `/` character. My data looks like this:

```
url
https://www.delish.com/food-news/news/jdhgkjdf/100-years-of-christmas
https://www.delish.com/food-news/news/100-years-of-christmas
```

The desired output is:

```
new_string
food-news
food-news
```

I have tried the following:

```
SPLIT(url, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(url, '/')) - 4)] AS new string
```

But because the URLs are not consistent, sometimes it grabs `food_news`, sometimes it grabs `www.delish.com`, that's why offset is not working in this particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
regexp_extract(url, net.host(url) || r'/([^/]+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

SPLIT(url, '/')[SAFE_OFFSET(ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(b.page_link, '.com/'))  +1)] AS new_string